# How to cache a dictionary in Django?

Tags: django, caching

I am using Django as my Webframework.

I have a method that takes really long ~10 sec to complete.
It returns a Dictionary which I then display in the templates.
This method is called on a POST request after a button click.

When the user reloads the page the View gets a GET request and all the results from before dont get displayed anymore.

How can I somehow cache the Dictionary so I can even display it on a get request when the user once did the POST request?

Comment: What about [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)?

Comment: lru cache could be possible but then user still has to click the button to show the results again